# Can I say "if class A is subclass of class B, type A must be subtype of type B"?

Tags: java, scala, subclassing, type-systems, subtyping

I have some understands about the relationship between `subtype` and `subclass`, but I'm not sure if they are correct.

### concrete classes (not generic/higher-order class)

Say in Java or Scala, if I declare some concrete classes or types:

```
class B

class A extends B
```

If class `A` is the subclass of class `B`, then type `A` must be subtype of type `B`?

And also, if type `A` is subtype of type `B`, then class `A` is subclass of class `B`? (assume `A` and `B` are both classes)

But they are true only if it's concrete class or types

### higher-order classes/types

But for higher-order types, this not true, right? Say:

```
class A[+T]
```

Then type `A[String]` is subtype of type `A[Object]`, but `A[String]` is not a subclass of `A[Object]`, right?

Comment: Java doesn't have a concept of "type", except for the scalar primitives (which can't be subtyped).

Comment: We can't talk about generics for Java the same way we do for Scala. They do things differently. Pick one.

Comment: @HotLicks Incorrect; in Java, both classes and interfaces are types.

Comment: @chrylis - In which case "class" and "type" are essentially synonymous (except for scalars) and so the question is meaningless.

Comment: @HotLicks Not entirely synonymous, but every class is a type, and the question does appear to be meaningless for Java.

Comment: @HotLicks Even in Java "class" and "type" are distinct concepts. Interfaces are types but not classes. `ArrayList<Integer>` is a type but not a class, even though `ArrayList` is a class.

Comment: The JLS actually does have a concept of "subtype", but it's not really intended for normal programmers to use.  It's used, for example, by the rule that says Java will pick the most specific type when deciding between two overloads.  Language specifications have a tendency to define their own terms for their own use.

Answer (score 3):

Almost yes to everything in the question - you can describe `A` and `B` as being subtypes even when they are generic classes, as I explain below.

There are only two ways that "`A` subclasses `B`" and "`A` subtypes `B`" may not be equivalent:

1, Traits/interfaces can be part of the inheritance hierarchy but can't be described as classes, and therefore can't be part of a subclassing relationship. You can use "extends" to express this more general relationship, as in `A` extends `B`.

2, Generic classes aren't simple types, but are type constructors (i.e. higher-kinded types). So with:

```
class B[T]
class A[T] extends B[T]
```

It is correct to say that "`A[T]` subtypes `B[T]`" but `A[T]` and `B[T]` aren't classes and can't have a subclassing relationship. It is correct to say that "`A` subclasses `B`" and also that "`A` subtypes `B`", but in this case you are describing relationships between higher-kinded types.

Note that Scala, unlike Java, allows type parameters to be declared co- or contravariant. If you have `class C[-T, +U]` and two types `A` and `B` and `A` subtypes `B`, then `C[B, A]` subtypes `C[A, B]`, but obviously there is no subclassing relationship there.